# import series-like data file into pandas

Tags: python, pandas, text, dataframe, series

Here is an example of the data file:

```
 =====
 name          aaa
 place         paaa
 date          Thu Oct 1 12:02:03 2015
 load_status   198
 add_name      naaa
 [---blank line---]
 =====
 name          bbb
 place         pbbb
 date          Thu Oct 3 21:20:36 2015
 load_status   2000.327
 add_name      nbbb
 [---blank line---]
```

In one file there might be hundreds of records like that.

I would like to get a pandas object looking like this:

```
   name | place | date                    | load_status | add_name
   ---------------------------------------------------------------
   aaa  | paaa  | Thu Oct 1 12:02:03 2015 | 198         | naaa
   bbb  | pbbb  | Thu Oct 3 21:20:36 2015 | 2000.327    | nbbb
```

Number of fields in each record is the same: so all records has some 'name', 'place' and etc.

I can transpose the file with "bash+grep+awk" and then read it as csv but it's not practical for users who has only Python and Windows.
Transposing file using Python and then read it as csv looks like overkill as I expect Pandas should be able to handle this case some how.

I thought of Series+dtypes and read_table - but couldn't make them work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple loop in Python. You'll have to do some cleaning afterwards, and some checking afterwards, but this should get you started.

```
import pandas as pd

records = []
this_record = {}
with open(input_fn, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == '':
            records.append(this_record)
            this_record = {}
            continue
        elif line.startswith('='):
            continue
        line = line.split()
        this_record[line[0]] = ' '.join(line[1:]).strip()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
```

Comment: While this solution worked like a charm for my file of 54 records, I'm still wondering is there any way to let panda text file parser to do this for me. For example, if I will remove basically redundant extra record delimiter `=====` from the file lines (I can also add `blank-line` to the beginning of the file so that record delimiter will be consistent through the file: 2 lines - one is blank one is of `=` signs).